# Change ResultSet to TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE in Scala

Tags: sql-server, scala, database-connection, resultset

I'm using Scala to connect to a database. The connection is working and I can execute SQL with the output stored in a ResultSet. I now need to change the ResultSet to TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE so that I can point to specific rows in the ResultSet. This is a section of my code (connection details omitted for data privacy):

```
import java.sql.{Connection, ResultSet, SQLException, Statement}

object test extends App {

def connectURL (): java.sql. Connection  = {

val url  =  "connection url"
val username =  sys.env.get("USER").get    
val password =  sys.env.get("PASS").get

 
Class. forName ( "driver name" ) 
var connection = java.sql.DriverManager. getConnection ( url ,  username ,  password )
     connection  
}

val query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1"

val con : java.sql. Connection  =  connectURL (); // creates the connection
val st  =  con . createStatement (ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE); // creates connection statement
val rs  =  st.executeQuery(query); // executes the query and stores as ResultsSet 

}
```

This gives the error: ***overloaded method value createStatement***

The `con` variable is of type Connection, `st` is of type Statement and `rs` is of type ResultSet. I've tried changing val to the types above, and I get this error: ***value st is not a member of object java.sql.Statement***

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `createStatement(int resultSetType, int resultSetConcurrency)` takes two parameter you are giving only one.

Comment: @RamanMishra Thank you for highlighting this. I now get an error where my executeQuery function will only work if `st` is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` and `CONCUR_READ_ONLY` (i.e. Default). I have used `supportsResultSetConcurrency(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)` to see if the database supports my desired ResultSet type and it outputs true. Am a bit stuck here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see javadocs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html
createStatement is defined with either 0,2, or 3 parameters

Comment: Thank you for highlighting this. I now get an error where my executeQuery function will only work if `st` is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` and `CONCUR_READ_ONLY` (i.e. Default). I have used `supportsResultSetConcurrency(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)` to see if the database supports my desired ResultSet type and it outputs true. Am a bit stuck here